# Google Graph from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, graph

I have a query in MYSQL that returns a table like the following one:

```
Name |    Date    | Amount
--------------------------
Peter| 2012-03-01 | 7
Marc | 2012-03-01 | 2
Marc | 2012-03-02 | 1
Peter| 2012-03-03 | 2
Peter| 2012-03-07 | 9
Marc | 2012-03-07 | 3
Jake | 2012-03-09 | 5
```

I would like to show this information into a google line graph, how would I convert this query result to a data source for a google graph displaying the values per person on every date? Would it also be possible to make a cumulative graph for example: Peter's value on 2012-03-03 would be 9 (7+2).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: fetch the data, package it up in a format google expects, and send it to google. that's about all we can say, since you haven't said which language(s) you're using, and we're not here to do your job for you anyways.

Comment: I'm using html and php. Sorry if this question wasn't good. I have tried getting it in the right format. But I just can't figure it out!